# Should i make an instance of my controller for every instance of my ListItem?

Tags: java, swing, view, controller

I have a JPanel which will contain a list of ListItems. I was planning to use a controller for my views to sepperate the Logic from swing components. 
Now my question is should i make a instance of my controller for every instance of my ListItem or should i use the same instance for every instance of my ListItem?

```
public interface ListItemController {
   public void stateWasRequested(ListItemView view);
}
public interface ListItemView {
   public void loadFields(List<Map<String, Object>> defs);
   public ListItemController getListItemController();
}
```

Comment: *"ow my question is should i make a instance of my controller for every instance of my ListItem"* - No. `ListItem` is a model, it should already contain the required logic.  A controller would be used to bridge the UI and the model (in a traditional MVC), allowing communication between them.  Each instance of a controller would be responsible for managing an instance of `ListModel` and `ListItemView`, but multiple controllers could managing the same instances of `ListModel` and `ListItemView` either together or mixed with different instances.

Comment: I think using mvc for my Project would bei overkill because its just a simple client for a REST API. So i planned to skip my Model and just load/save the data in my controller. The API-Client is already implemented just without gui.